# Filter content in localStorage

Tags: filter, local-storage

I'm using the localStorage to store some data the user may see and some it isn't allowed to see.

Now I'm iterating over the whole localStorage to get the data to display in a list, but the issue is that all my other data comes with it (such as some variables, etc...)

```
for (i = 0; i < tracks_recorded; i++) {
    $("#history_tracklist").append("<li><a href='#track_info'>" + window.localStorage.key(i) + "</a></li>");
}
```

How can I filter the content of the localStorage to hide the "City" key from displaying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tracklist = $('#history_tracklist'),
    $info = $('<li><a href='#track_info'></a></li>');
for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
  var key = localStorage.key(i);
  if (key !== 'City') {
    $tracklist.append($info.clone().text(key));
  }
}
```

Oh, and if you are looking for easier ways to use localStorage or sessionStorage (including namespaces to keep your "private" stuff separate, you might consider using something like my
 https://github.com/nbubna/store library.  You don't really need it just for the simple case you describe, but if things get more complex, the richer API will come in handy.

Comment: Woah, thanks! That was just what I needed. I changed your solution a bit (to make things more readable) for (i = 0; i < tracks_recorded; i++) {
        if (window.localStorage.key(i) !== 'stad') {
            $("#history_tracklist").append("<li><a href='#track_info'>" + window.localStorage.key(i) + "</a></li>");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

First, a hat tip to @Nathan Bubna for his store2.js API.

Now, for the OPs question: filtering local storage content. May I suggest using [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), a handy utility that lets you transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String. It also offers simple data scrambling, intelligent string compression, query by key as well as query by value, and it helps enforce shared storage segmentation in the same domain.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Examples:

```
localDataStorage.set( 'key1', 'Belgian' );
localDataStorage.set( 'key2', 1200.0047 );
localDataStorage.set( 'key3', true );
localDataStorage.set( 'key4', { 'RSK' : [1,'3',5,'7',9] } );
localDataStorage.set( 'key5', null );

localDataStorage.get( 'key1' );   -->   'Belgian'
localDataStorage.get( 'key2' );   -->   1200.0047
localDataStorage.get( 'key3' );   -->   true
localDataStorage.get( 'key4' );   -->   Object {RSK: Array(5)}
localDataStorage.get( 'key5' );   -->   null
```

As you can see, the primitive values are respected. Now in your case, we may wish to store a 'City' key in obfuscated form:

```
>localDataStorage.safeset( 'City', 'Portland', 'our-secret-key' );
```

This obfuscates the data stored in local storage. It's not quite encrypted, but it's certainly not plaintext either. In my machine it looks like this in storage:

```
ڕ³¼୎П٠ࢭ\B۳ث
```

Now, when we retrieve it...

```
>localDataStorage.safeget( 'City', 'our-secret-key' );  -->
```

... we will get:

```
>"Portland"
```

exactly what we started with, letting localDataStorage protect the data for us.